# How might a comment affect code?

Tags: comments, wikipedia

I was reading an answer over on Software Engineering SE about factory methods and their uses. [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/253264/255555) refers to "cargo cult" programming which referred me to a wikipedia article and from there I followed the link to the "deep magic" page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(programming)).

On this page I found a very interesting statement:

> Any comment that has an effect on the code is magic.

So my question is this. How might one create a comment that has an effect on the code? Are there any examples of this in the wild or is this merely a postulation with no grounding in reality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a naïvely interpreted language (without e.g. a bytecode compilation stage), comments will have effects on the execution times of the interpreter by affecting I/O operations to read the code. With sufficiently precise engineering of time-critical sections to a particular target architecture (or plain bad luck), you could get different execution paths, depending on the presence, absence or length of comments. Which is in itself a reason to stay away from purely interpreted languages… ah, MS-BASIC, how little I miss you!

Comment: Jesus that must cause some difficult to debug issues... I always assumed interpreted languages just carried on to the next statement upon encountering the comment break character(s)